# using motion on raspberry pi for webcam streaming issue

Tags: webcam, raspberry-pi, motion, raspbian

I have a USB webcam (unknown make, no markings) thats been detected fine on my Raspberry Pi.

This is the output of lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:608f Microdia PC Camera (SN9C103 + OV7630)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1267:0103 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc G-720 Keyboard
```

However when i run motion, using /dev/video0 with the only default config changed the resolution and setting the webcam host off so that i can stream it on a network. 
This is my log when i run motion

```
Log of motion -n 

[0] Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] Motion 3.2.12 Started
[0] ffmpeg LIBAVCODEC_BUILD 3482368 LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD 3478784
[0] Thread 1 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] motion-httpd/3.2.12 running, accepting connections
[0] motion-httpd: waiting for data on port TCP 8080
[1] Thread 1 started
[1] cap.driver: "sonixb"
[1] cap.card: "USB camera"
[1] cap.bus_info: "usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2"
[1] cap.capabilities=0x05000001
[1] - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] - READWRITE
[1] - STREAMING
[1] Config palette index 8 (YU12) doesn't work.
[1] Supported palettes:
[1] 0: S910 (S910)
[1] 1: BA81 (BA81)
[1] Selected palette BA81
[1] Test palette BA81 (480x640)
[1] Adjusting resolution from 480x640 to 160x120.
[1] Using palette BA81 (160x120) bytesperlines 160 sizeimage 19200 colorspace 00000008
[1] found control 0x00980900, "Brightness", range 0,255 
[1]     "Brightness", default 127, current 127
[1] found control 0x00980911, "Exposure", range 0,1023 
[1]     "Exposure", default 66, current 66
[1] found control 0x00980912, "Automatic Gain (and Exposure)", range 0,1 
[1]     "Automatic Gain (and Exposure)", default 1, current 1
[1] found control 0x00980913, "Gain", range 0,255 
[1]     "Gain", default 127, current 127
[1] mmap information:
[1] frames=4
[1] 0 length=20480
[1] 1 length=20480
[1] 2 length=20480
[1] 3 length=20480
[1] Using V4L2
[1] Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] v4l2_next: VIDIOC_DQBUF: EIO (s->pframe 0): Input/output error
[1] v4l2_next: VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
[1] v4l2_next: VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
[1] v4l2_next: VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
[1] v4l2_next: VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
[1] Error capturing first image
[1] Started stream webcam server in port 8081
[1] v4l2_next: VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
[1] Video device fatal error - Closing video device
[1] Closing video device /dev/video0
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
[1] cap.driver: "sonixb"
[1] cap.card: "USB camera"
[1] cap.bus_info: "usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2"
[1] cap.capabilities=0x05000001
[1] - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] - READWRITE
[1] - STREAMING
[1] Config palette index 8 (YU12) doesn't work.
[1] Supported palettes:
[1] 0: S910 (S910)
[1] 1: BA81 (BA81)
[1] Selected palette BA81
[1] Test palette BA81 (480x640)
[1] Adjusting resolution from 480x640 to 160x120.
[1] Using palette BA81 (160x120) bytesperlines 160 sizeimage 19200 colorspace 00000008
[1] found control 0x00980900, "Brightness", range 0,255 
[1]     "Brightness", default 127, current 127
[1] found control 0x00980911, "Exposure", range 0,1023 
[1]     "Exposure", default 66, current 66
[1] found control 0x00980912, "Automatic Gain (and Exposure)", range 0,1 
[1]     "Automatic Gain (and Exposure)", default 1, current 1
[1] found control 0x00980913, "Gain", range 0,255 
[1]     "Gain", default 127, current 127
[1] mmap information:
[1] frames=4
[1] 0 length=20480
[1] 1 length=20480
[1] 2 length=20480
[1] 3 length=20480
[1] Using V4L2
[1] Camera has finally become available
[1] Camera image has different width and height from what is in the config file. You should fix that
[1] Restarting Motion thread to reinitialize all image buffers to new picture dimensions
[1] Thread exiting
[1] Calling vid_close() from motion_cleanup
[1] Closing video device /dev/video0
[0] Motion thread 1 restart
[1] Thread 1 started
[1] config image height (120) is not modulo 16
[1] Could not fetch initial image from camera
[1] Motion continues using width and height from config file(s)
[1] Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] Started stream webcam server in port 8081
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
[1] config image height (120) is not modulo 16
[0] httpd - Finishing
[0] httpd Closing
[0] httpd thread exit
[1] Thread exiting
[0] Motion terminating
```

The light on the camera comes on at the start and then goes off again, does anyone recognise any of the errors i'm getting?

Thanks!

Comment: my webcam is compatible with l4v2, and i have tried other video input methods such as fswebcam. Still to no avail.
One thing I haven't tried, is using a powered usb hub, currently i'm just using it straight from the board with 700mA, it may not be enough to run my webcam.

Comment: By retrying multiple times with my usb keyboard and hdmi cable disconnected, i am able to get motion to take some pictures before failing with an input output error.
All pictures looked like this - http://s7.postimage.org/mjb0z2wwn/01_20130115174957_01.jpg
Therefore i am going to assume that i need more power and am going to buy a powered usb hub and give that a try

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the height and width for the image in the conf file to your camera specification.  Mine didnt work until I set height 640 width 480.  Streams great!  Just need to figure out the patch for the webstream authentication.  currently I have this streaming to my webserver that requires a login but this can be bypassed if someone enters my IP plus the port im streaming on.

Comment: I did play around with the resolution, i think in the example ive posted i set the height and width round the wrong way - Adjusting resolution from 480x640 to 160x120. so i will try that.

Comment: Sorry...width 680 height 480

Comment: yeah thats what i meant, in my example it resizes 480x640 to 160x120, so i should set it 680x480

Answer (score 1):

Even if configured in the *conf* file differently, motion uses the possible resolution it detects when it runs (at least in my experience).

Also, it seems an unsupported palette is set in the *conf* file and motion picks one of the two it detects as supported. Have you tried changing the palette setting to "0" (S910) in the *conf* file?

Lastly, the Pi's USB support has some known and as of now unsolved issues regarding big chunks of data. Lowering the framerate may also help in other cases (in this case, I think, I wouldn't help, since the process already fails with the first image).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the log:

```
config image height (120) is not modulo 16
```

So you need a different image resolution.

See what your device supports with

```
$ uvcdynctrl -f
```

Pick one that has a y-resolution that is a multiple of 16.
E.g. 640x480 if that one is listed for your camera.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try guvcview instead of motion. It runs faster and gives a far better picture on my Pi. It runs under X.

Two notes of guvcview - set POWER LINE FREQUENCY to your local mains freq.
- set resolution to 640 x 480.

guvcview takes about 50% processor power. Yes, use a USB Hub too!

Unh.

Comment: I tried, but didnt work. Will wait for my usb hub to arrive and try again with motion

Answer (score 0):

Try `v2l4-ctl --list-format-ext` to see what combinations of pixel format and image size are supported on your camera. The `S910` is a cheap old camera, you might want to upgrade.

Comment: That must be `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`.